# How Remove transparent area from png file?

Tags: php, imagemagick, png

I get text from input text form and create PNG file like:

[image]
[image]

if you look at the example png file, find those have some transparent area.
my goal is remove that with imagemagick or php GD.

is it possible?

Comment: Try this `convert input.png -transparent:red out.png`

Comment: Or just convert to JPEG which doesn't support transparency... `convert input.png output.jpg`

Comment: 1:-transparent:red not work! 2: I need png file to compose it over another picture. 3: any solution?

Comment: Sorry `convert input.png -transparent red out.png`

Comment: it is not working, can you try with my sample file?thank you

Comment: Your image has a 4-bit palettised alpha channel - I have never even heard of such a thing and can't think how to handle it for the moment - it is late. I will sleep on it. What I mean by 4-bit transparency is, the background appears to have varying transparency in 16 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mark for your solution and your help, but the best solution by thank a lot from

[Joakim Carlsten](http://www.adtradeconsulting.se/author/joakim/)
http://www.adtradeconsulting.se/remove-transparency-around-image-with-imagemagick/

all we need use -trim like:

```
exec('convert source.png -trim result.png')
```

[image]

As you see.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution:

```
convert NyRQK.png -background red -alpha remove out.png
```

Of course, you can change `red` to `white` or any other colour you like.

[image]

Comment: it's good, but i need to remove transparent area, not fill that with another color...